# Azure Pipeline NodeTool task fails on mac Agent

Tags: node.js, azure-pipelines

I have a workflow with two jobs. First job uses a windows agent and runs the NodeTool task installation successfully. Second job uses the mac agent and runs the same NodeTool but returns an error `##[error]Directory does not exist: /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/node/0.9.0/x64/bin`.

Here is a relevant snippet

**Windows job**

```
 jobs:
  - job: build_on_win
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
       versionSpec: '14.18.0.x'
```

**Mac Job**

```
 - job: build_on_mac
    pool:
      vmImage: 'macOS-latest'
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
       versionSpec: '14.18.0.x'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure Pipeline NodeTool task fails on mac Agent

It seems that the version you specified does not match the Mac system, please using `14.x` instead of `14.18.0.x`：

```
 jobs:
  - job: build_on_Mac
    pool:
      vmImage: 'macOS-latest'
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
       versionSpec: '14.x'
```

The test result：

[image]